# Goでgo routineがdeadlockする

Tags: go

下記のGoのコードでWalkerを実行するとgo routineがdeadlockされてしまいます。
deadlockされずに全てのNodeのValueを実行するにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?
そして、なぜdeadlockになってしまうのでしょうか?

参考: https://golang.org/doc/play/tree.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

type Node struct {
    Value               int64
    Left, Right, Parent *Node
}

func (n *Node) Insert(num int64) *Node {
    if num > n.Value {
        if n.Left == nil {
            n.Left = &Node{Parent: n, Value: num}
            return n
        }
        n.Left.Insert(num)
    } else if num < n.Value {
        if n.Right == nil {
            n.Right = &Node{Parent: n, Value: num}
            return n
        }
        n.Right.Insert(num)
    }
    return n
}

func (n *Node) Walk(x chan int64) {
    if n == nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(n.Value)
    n.Left.Walk(x)
    x <- n.Value
    n.Right.Walk(x)

}

func Walker(n *Node) chan int64 {
    ch := make(chan int64)
    go func() {
        n.Walk(ch)
    }()
    return ch

}

func Randint(min, max int64) int64 {
    f64_min := float64(min)
    f64_max := float64(max)
    r := rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
    return int64(math.Floor(r.Float64()*(f64_max-f64_min+1)) + f64_min)
}

func main() {
    root := &Node{Value: 1264523}
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        y := Randint(0, 12345667)
        root.Insert(y)
    }
    ch := Walker(root)
    for {
        value, ok := <-ch
        if !ok {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println(value)

    }
}
```

Comment: goroutine の終了時に channel を閉じていないからだと思います。
`go func() { n.Walk(ch); close(ch); }()`

Comment: @argus なぜ、チャンネルを閉じていないとdeadlockになってしまうのでしょうか?

Comment: 上記のプログラムの場合、`ch` にデータを送信する goroutine が channel を閉じないままに実行を終了すると、`value, ok := <-ch` では永久にデータの受信待ち状態になってしまいます(データが送信されることがないため)。この状態を検出してエラー(deadlock)としています。

Comment: @argus ありがとうございます!丁寧な解説でよくわかりました!!